# GitLab Unicorn web server is not running

Tags: gitlab

I installed gilab using these instructions: [gitlab.com](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md)

When gitlab start, I get a message in the console: The GitLab Unicorn web server is not running.

When I go to server, in the browser i get 502 error.

It is `unicorn.stderr.log`: [link to plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/aIvTjKqUgPItyvESsH3S?p=catalogue)

This error can occur because of what?

NGINX config: [link to plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/afR6SkSwKA9k5G6QvghC?p=catalogue)

gitlab.yml: [link to plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/cc7bxqBVLGTsKrih11Aa?p=catalogue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line within your Unicorn logs highlights the problem:

```
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:177:in `rescue in spec': Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'mysql2'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord). (Gem::LoadError)
```

You have specified that you're going to use MySQL within the config/database.yml file, but the Gem `mysql2` doesn't appear to be installed. The `mysql2` Gem contains the necessary libraries for interacting with your MySQL database.

The following command:

`gem list`

Will list the Gems that are currently installed, allowing you to verify whether `mysql2` is amongst them.

This section of the installation document covers the installation of the necessary Gems for your GitLab install:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md#install-gems